# How is this unexpected comparison output produced?

Tags: python, python-2.7, comparison, tuples

Why do I get a tuple of three elements from the following expression?

```
>>> 1,2 == 1,2
(1, False, 2)
```

Comment: What do you mean *"how"*?! You're evaluating `(1, (2 == 1), 2)`. What were you expecting? Did you mean `(1, 2) == (1, 2)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expression `1,2 == 1,2` is interpreted as a tuple of 3 elements, `1`, `2 == 1` (i.e, `False`), and `2`.

Answer (score 10):

Because the `==` operator has a [higher operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) than the `,` operator, your expression is parsed as:

```
1, (2 == 1), 2
```

producing a tuple with the literal `1`, the outcome of `2 == 1` -> `False`, and the literal `2`.

You can put parentheses around the `1, 2` tuples to force a different parsing order:

```
>>> (1, 2) == (1, 2)
True
```

Comment: Got it now,+1 `>>> 5,6,8 == 1,2,3, 5==5
>>> (5, 6, False, 2, 3, True)`

Comment: @VivekSable yes - the spaces in your example are irrelevant, only the operators (and their precedence) matter

Comment: hmm I just playing on Python Shell to check different cases and there result.